# how can i make a combination of few variables and keep specific set based on regression

Tags: r

I try to make a example data as follows:

```
set.seed(1)            # for reproducible example
x <- sample(100*20)
x <- matrix(x, nc = 20)     # 20 predictor
y <- 1 + 2*x[,1] + 3*x[,2] + 4*x[,3] + 5*x[,7] + 6*x[,8] + 7*x[,9] + rnorm(100)  # y depends on variables 1,2,3,7,8,9 only

df <- data.frame(y, as.matrix(x))
```

Now, I want to make a combination of 4 columns of x and keep all those combinations that the lm model has a R higher than 0.8

To make a model between Y and 4 variables of X , for example one can use

```
fit = lm(Y~.,data=df[,c(2:6)])
```

I want to have all combinations of 4 variables from these 20 columns that their R regression is higher than 0.8

Can someone please comment?

Comment: you should take a look at `regsubset` from package `leaps`

Comment: @agenis thanks, do you have any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following my comment, I suggest using the `leaps` package that provides an algorithm to test in an exhaustive way every combination of variables of a model formula, and returns some indicators (R-squared, BIC, etc.).

You can treat the results to get the list of variables that suits your criteria (here I took 0.85 limit to get a smaller list of models). First, fit the model and specify the limit of 4 variables, and we will keep only the 20 best models (there are in total 19380 possible models of 4 variables...):

```
library(leaps)
fit <- regsubsets(y~., df, nvmax=4, nbest=20)
```

Subset the output table (it's a boolean table with TRUE/FALSE for each variable kept inside the model) depending on the r-squared limit (it's stored in another output of the summary):

```
mytable <- data.frame(tail(summary(fit)$which, 20)[which(tail(summary(fit)$rsq, 20)>0.85), ])
```

Arrange it to get the variable names of the best models, in transposed format, the first one being the best one in R²:

```
output <- t(apply(mytable, 1, function(x) names(mytable)[x]))
####      [,1]           [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] 
#### [1,] "X.Intercept." "X3" "X7" "X8" "X9" 
#### [2,] "X.Intercept." "X2" "X7" "X8" "X9" 
#### [3,] "X.Intercept." "X1" "X7" "X8" "X9" 
#### [4,] "X.Intercept." "X7" "X8" "X9" "X15"
#### [5,] "X.Intercept." "X4" "X7" "X8" "X9"
```

If you need to use one of these models for a fit, you could retrieve the formula like this:

```
as.formula(paste("y ~ ", paste(output[1, -1], collapse=" + ")))
#### y ~ X3 + X7 + X8 + X9
```

Or simply using `reformulate`, thanks to @Ben Bolker 's suggestion:

```
reformulate(output[1, -1], response="y")
```

**EDIT: modeling your data with lasso regression.**

I use the script adapted from Hastie&Tishirani, and you must also load these helper functions [here](http://julien.cremeriefamily.info/doc/teachings/ensiie/functions_mpr.r). I suggest first you get your hands on this technique.  First I create the data and split a training set:

```
library(glmnet); set.seed(6)
train.ratio <- 0.75 
x      <- model.matrix(y~., df)[, -1]           
y      <- df$y
train.ind  <-   sample(1:nrow(x), floor(train.ratio * nrow(x)))
x.train    <-   x[ train.ind, ]; y.train    <-   y[ train.ind  ]
x.test     <-   x[-train.ind, ]; y.test     <-   y[-train.ind  ]
n          <-   nrow(x); n.train    <-   nrow(x.train); n.test     <-   nrow(x.test)
```

Then I do the model calibration and compute test error

```
grid <- 10^seq(4, -2, length=100) # increase range if needed

lasso.mod <- glmnet(x.train, y.train, alpha=1, lambda=grid) 
err.lasso <- 1/n.test * colSums((y.test - lasso.mod$a0[1] - x.test %*% lasso.mod$beta)^2)
```

Plot the different results

```
par(mfrow = c(2, 2))
frac.lasso <- plot.path(t(lasso.mod$beta), err = err.lasso)
plot.coef(t(lasso.mod$beta), lasso.mod$lambda, err.lasso)
plot.err(err.lasso, frac.lasso)
plot.err(err.lasso, lasso.mod$lambda)
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
```

[image]
Eventually find out what the best model is (cool, it's the same than previously! but different coefs).

```
best <- lasso.mod$beta[, which.min(err.lasso)]; best[best!=0]
####        X3        X7        X8        X9 
#### 0.2572322 1.4933962 1.7868181 2.4447500
```

You can also ask all cases containing 4 variables (here they are the same, differ only the lambda value and coefs)

```
lasso.mod$beta[, which(colSums(lasso.mod$beta!=0)==4)]
```

Comment: don't forget `?reformulate`, which is a slightly cleaner way to do your last step ...

Comment: @agenis thanks for your solution, would it also be possible to have the output with their R values for each set too ?

Comment: I realized it was a solution to the wrong problem, that's why I deleted it ... I will undelete it but don't think it will be useful.

Comment: well it's one of the output of the summary function. you can do like this `cbind(output, head(tail(summary(fit)$rsq, 20), nrow(output)))`

Comment: @agenis sorry for trouble, I am getting into trouble, when i use more than 1000 variables, I get this error, do you know how to solve it Error in leaps.exhaustive(a, really.big) : 
  Exhaustive search will be S L O W, must specify really.big=T
In addition: Warning message:
In leaps.setup(x, y, wt = wt, nbest = nbest, nvmax = nvmax, force.in = force.in,  :
  3000  linear dependencies found

Comment: yes you must specify `rally.big=TRUE` in your case. but i didn't realize you had so many variables, it's probable that the algo will take forever... What *kind* of data are you modeling!? you should maybe think of another method of finding best variables, like regularization or PLS, or stuff like that.

Comment: @agenis It is a microarray data, I know it is not common but I have some ideas and that is why I am doing this step. No PLS is based on decomposition and not useful in this case but thanks for suggesting it. Now I get an error like Error in model.frame.default(data = df, rally.big = TRUE, formula = V1 ~  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for '(rally.big)')

Comment: really.big. please check the help file for the correct spelling

Comment: but i maintain that i'd rather do a lasso regression on it and tune the lambda value so that you conserve only 4 variables.

Comment: @agenis would it be possible to give me the alternative using lasso ?

Comment: @agenis thanks you spent some times on this. I appreciate it and i will go through your solution. however, I accepted your solution already

Comment: The link to http://julien.cremeriefamily.info/doc/teachings/ensiie/functions_mpr.r is dead.